# mysql : Can't find record in table

Tags: java, mysql

In my java program an update query is used like below,

```
update unsub_tbl set stat=1 where stat=0 and emp_id='4441' and action='1';
```

if `unsub_tbl` is empty, then trying to update using above update query gives exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Can't find record in 'unsub_tbl'

But it's not giving the exception all the time for same condition. Why does it only give the exception sometimes?

Comment: Can you give an example of a table for which it gives the exception and for which it does not? Or alternatively a query for which it gives the exception and for which it does not? I am not so sure that the conditions are really the same for the cases where you do and do not get the exception.

Comment: in same table only sometimes its giving exception and sometimes not. with above qry.  i am sure condition are same.

Comment: Something must be different, it should not be non-deterministic, are you sure that the table is the same? That means, that the contents did not change?

Comment: Are you using any kind of `ORM`, if so may be the caching operation are causing such unexpected results.

Comment: i am sure i am using same table same content.

Comment: I dont know abt ORM and i am sure i m nt using.

Comment: which mysql version you are using?

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.jar

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a bug with MySQL 4.0.14+

Refer [MySQL Bugs](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1574)

Comment: The bug is present for MySQL versions higher than 4.0.14 according to the tracker. So, it must be present in 5.1.5.